# GLIBC_2.33 not found in raspberry pi python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, glibc, libc, google-cloud-vision

**Error Trace:**

ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)

**Scenario:**

I'm using *google cloud vision* api to detect text in images. The program works fine on laptop but gives the above mentioned error when ran in raspberry pi. I've searched a lot but couldn't find any working solution. I'd really appreciate if any one could let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling `grpcio` and `grpcio-status` (mine had version `1.46.3` installed for both) and installing version `1.44.0` solved it for me:

```
pip uninstall grpcio 
pip uninstall grpcio-status 
pip install grpcio==1.44.0 --no-binary=grpcio
pip install grpcio-tools==1.44.0 --no-binary=grpcio-tools
```

You can check your installed versions with `pip list`.

Note: installing `grpcio` and `grpcio-status` takes a really long time. About 15 to 20 minutes each.

Originally posted here: https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/vjbL3IdZ2Vk/m/EcKSeD4eAgAJ

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a small hint: `pip install grpcio==1.44.0` alone failed for me with the same error as in the original question. The key here was the `--no-binary` argument. It makes python skip the installers and instead compile everything on your system, honoring your available glibc version. It would problably have worked for newer `grpcio` versions too...

Comment: @user3792852 thank you, I'd try a newer version if the install didn't take so long

Comment: Newer versions fail for me with `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`. Happily pip seems to keep trying lower versions until it reaches 1.44.0, which works.

Answer (score 2):

GLIBC and the kernel of the OS go hand-in-hand; you basically need a newer version of your OS, if you need a more recent GLIBC

the version of the GLIBC can be quickly found out with the following command:
`ldd --version`

Comment: My raspberry pi has OS 10 Buster. Should i upgrade it to OS 11 ?

Comment: I'm running with OS 11 Bullseye but, as other answers say, the libc version is baked into the kernel. It's possible a fresh download of the OS image may include a newer version, but I can't find any resource that confirms this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried building glibc 2.33+ alongside the glibc that come in raspberry pi? Something along [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119083/upgrading-libc-libc6-raspberry-pi-os-rasbian-buster) and comments to use `buildroot`

Comment: The linked answer sounds like going down a deep rabbit hole...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after installing tflite-runtime 2.12.0, and I found that installing tflite-runtime 2.11.0 got rid of it.
The wheel files for your processor/python combo can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/2.11.0/#files